# Change App Overview Title Bar Color (Android & Ionic)

Tags: android, ionic-framework, colors

Is there a way to change the marked color below? I'm using using Ionic v3.x and couldn't find anything here and within Ionic docs. Thanks upfront for any tips!

[image: Android App Overview Title Bar Color]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Header Color plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/header-color/) is used to change the header color in multitask view.

Plugin github page: https://github.com/tomloprod/cordova-plugin-headercolor

**Example from Ionic documentation:**

```
import { HeaderColor } from '@ionic-native/header-color';

constructor(private headerColor: HeaderColor) { }

...

this.headerColor.tint('#becb29');
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked fine for me! Just adjusted the settings via config.xml after installing the plugin.

Comment: And the title color in overview?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// set status bar to white
this.statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#ffffff');
```

Doc link:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/status-bar/

Comment: Thanks for your reply Pratik but this StatusBar setting only changes the status bar to the desired color, not the marked title bar in the picture above.
[Screenshot of StatusBar changes](http://i.imgur.com/Qx7zwlj.jpg)